# Using guard with a non-optional value assignment

Tags: swift

**This is not a question about optional arrays, as one can see in the answers.**

I like using `guard` because it makes your intensions clear. I've used it both for the optional version like this...

```
guard let c = MyOptionalArray else { return }
```

as well as for more traditional bounds checking on non-optionals...

```
guard MyArray.count > 0 else { return }
```

But now I'd like to use that `count` in following code. So I did...

```
guard let c = MyArray.count > 0 else { return }
```

which doesn't work, obviously, so I did what should...

```
guard let c = parts.count where c > 1 else { return }
```

But that says `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'`. Now I understand the error, and tried a bunch of seemingly obvious changes to the format, but no go. Is there no way to use guard as an assignment on a non-optional value? This seems like something it should be able to do.

Comment: Is `parts` and optional array?

Comment: It is, but that's besides the point in a way. Depending on what you think `guard` is for, it should definitely handle this case. But as @Gavin notes below, it does handle this, with a little jiggery.

Comment: Indeed it's very important if `parts` is optional. If it is then you can write this     `guard let c = parts?.count where c > 1 else { return }`

Comment: If parts were optional the compiler would **NOT** print this error: `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'`. Please check your code.

Comment: This is NOT ABOUT OPTIONAL ARRAYS. Answers about checking optional arrays will obviously not answer questions that are NOT about optional arrays.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you throw a `case` in there, it'll work. So as follows:

```
guard case let c = parts.count where c > 1 else { return }
```

Comment: I can't imagine why this works, but it does work perfectly. Thank you, this is something I would have never figured out on my own.

Comment: You can take a look at http://appventure.me/2015/08/20/swift-pattern-matching-in-detail/ to see other uses of `case`. If you go to section 7 on that page, you can see more information about using `guard case`.

Comment: Very nice example of when `guard case let` is useful

Comment: `Optional` is actually just an enum =))

Comment: And `isEmpty` is slightly faster than `c > 1`.

Comment: @duytph c > 1 and isEmpty are logically different. c > 0 and !c.isEmpty are equivalent (in case of checking for a non-empty array) but if the section of code you’re guarding is c[1] then isEmpty probably isn’t what you want. I’d also prefer using isEmpty where possible, but it’s not a logical drop-in replacement for the > 1 test.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice the details of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize an optional wrapping the non-optional:

```
guard let count = Optional([42].count), count > 0 else {
    return
}

guard let count = .some([42].count), count > 0 else {
    return
}
```

or cast it to an optional:

```
guard let count = [42].count as Int?, count > 0 else {
    return
}
```

As mentioned in other answers, `guard case let` also works:

```
guard case let count = [42].count, count > 0 else {
    return
}

guard case let count = [42].count where count > 0 else { 
    return
}
```

Comment: Why would you wrap a value into an optional, just to have to unwrap it later to be able to use it? Seems counterintuitive to me.

Comment: @Cristik Mainly it keeps it on one line / inside the statement, which depending on context can be preferable to the line above and limit scope.

Comment: I had a case where I needed to declare/unwrap 5 properties that had an intrinsic order. Only the 3rd property was non-optional. These solutions allow you to keep everything cleanly within the same statement and in order.

Comment: Still, seems a  little bit over-engineering, as the condition can be checked within the same guard without the optional boxing+unboxing.

Comment: @Cristik checked via `guard case let` you mean? The optional route is easier to deduce/remember IMO. Same result. Just another *option*.

Comment: Just `guard`, e.g. `guard let someOptional = someValue,\n someNonOptional.someProperty == anotherValue,\n ...`. Not sure if it makes sense in a comment, as I cannot add multiline code, `\n` stands for new line.

Comment: @Cristik There's also the scenario where that non-optional value in the middle needs to be used within the following logic block, but is also computed – casting to Optional allows that computation to happen only once, but also doesn't require the logic statement to be broken up.